# Logger Error when running through python

Tags: python

I have a python script that takes in a couple of command line arguments and executes a function. when I run it from shell it runs perfectly

```
$ ./test.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

But when I call it through another python function it throws an error

```
os.system("./test.py arg1 arg2 arg3")
```

This throws an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/redshift/PROJ/query/test.py", line 4, in <module>
    from new_main_queryAndProcess import main_queryAndProcess
  File "/var/redshift/PROJ/query/new_main_queryAndProcess.py", line 7, in <module>
    import mdr_lib as mdr
  File "/var/redshift/PROJ/query/mdr_lib.py", line 26, in <module>
    logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/config.py", line 76, in fileConfig
    formatters = _create_formatters(cp)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/config.py", line 109, in _create_formatters
    flist = cp["formatters"]["keys"]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/configparser.py", line 937, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'formatters'
256
```

Comment: I think your issue is related to path and relative path when you do `logging.config.fileConfig('logging.conf')`. From where are you running this new script ?

Comment: they are not in the same directory. But I tried with putting the absolute path of the logging.conf file but still it gave the same error